# How to Export SQL Server Database To A File For Later Import To Different Computer

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm using the Sql Server 2012 Import and Export data (64) i'm not sure what options i should be picking to do what i want. I just want to be able to export all the data in the database to a file which i can then send to my other machine and then import the database.

The databases just contains tables.

Comment: Right click the db, tasks, back it up to a .bak & restore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I upvoted the comment by @Alex K. as this, I believe, is the easiest way of accomplish what you want. Backup the database, when asked copy the .bak file where you think is better for your needs, maybe even you can copy it already in a place where the other PC has access. Then do the opposite on the other SQL Server instance on the other PC, restore the database from the .bak previously saved.

Here is [a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx#SSMSProcedure) to a detailed description on how to backup the database using SSMS.

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx) how to restore using the SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able copy the MDF to the other machine and attach it.

Step 1: Copy your file from PC-1 to PC-2 and put the file in the following folder (or where ever you installed the SQL Server data files):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\
```

Step 2:

```
USE [master]
GO

EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname='HotelProject',
@physname=N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\HotelProject.mdf'
GO
```

`@dbname` is the database name that you want to attach the file to.

`@phyname` is the path + filename where the MDF file is stored on the hard drive.

`N'` make the literal string NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR.

Use import/export when you only want part of the database, like a particular group of related tables.  I don't normally use this to export to a flat file, but [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3580216/SQL-Server-2005-Import--Export-Wizard.htm) is a good example on how to do it.

Comment: USE [master]
GO

EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @HotelProject='HotelProject',
@KHAN-PC=N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\HotelProject.mdf'
GO Whats @physname=N?

Comment: @user1638362 - updated my answer with your MDF.  I'm not sure if 2012 data files are installed in MSSQL10 or not, so make sure your path is correct.